# How to use RequireJS optimizer in Play framework?

Tags: requirejs, webjars, requirejs-optimizer, playframework-2.4

As advertised, the `rjs` in Play can

> ensure that any JavaScript resources referenced from within a WebJar
>   are automatically referenced from the jsdelivr CDN. In addition if any
>   .min.js file is found then that will be used in place of .js. An added
>   bonus here is that there is no change required to your html!

However, I cannot seem to get any of that to work.

1. I tried running my Play app in production mode, and all my webjar javascripts are still being referenced as local.
2. I do not see the `.min` version of javascript files being used in production.
3. I cannot get dependency injection to work in production mode. For example, when I want to inject `jquery` in my code like this

   define(['jquery'], function ($) {
       'use strict';
       console.log($.grep);
       return {
           sum: function (a, b) {
               return a + b;
           }
       };
   });

I can get this to work fine in dev mode, but in production mode, the `rjs` failed saying

```
[info] Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/khanguyen/Desktop/rjsdemo/target/web/rjs/build/js/jquery.js'
[info] In module tree:
[info]     main
[info]       app
[info] 
[info] Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/khanguyen/Desktop/rjsdemo/target/web/rjs/build/js/jquery.js'
[info] In module tree:
[info]     main
[info]       app
[info] 
[info]     at Error (native)
```

Obviously it is looking at the wrong location for jQuery, despite the config setup generated by Webjar

```
requirejs.config({"paths":{"jquery":["/webjars/jquery/1.11.1/jquery","jquery"]},"shim":{"jquery":{"exports":"$"}},"packages":[]})    }
```

to have the correct location for `jquery`.

I am using Play 2.4.0, with `pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest)` setup in my build.sbt.

Please let me know where I got it wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I wonder if it's a configuration problem and have thus opened an issue here https://github.com/webjars/sample-play2/issues/7

Comment: Here is what I noticed so far, without clear explanation for why things work or do not work. You must use Classic Webjars. When you declare your `paths` in main.js, wrap the urls in [square brackets]. I decided to ditch the Webjar module because I don't want 2 versions of the same file. Let me know how it goes. I will write  post with instruction once I figure out how to put this together.

Comment: You ditched the webjar module? So you're not using them anymore? That would be unfortunate. I still wonder if we're simply missing some configuration or maybe there's an incompatibility (sbt-rjs hasn't been updated in a while).

Comment: Just to clarify, I use Webjars, but I do not use the webjar-play module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that RequireJS optimization support does not apply to all Webjars, but rather limited to Classic Webjars. 
[image]

Even then, a webjar build file has to be included with the regular module in order for rjs to work.
[image]

If you look at the jQuery classic webjar, for example, you will see that a special webjar build instruction is included. Take a look at that file for your information.
[image]

Once you have identify a webjar that is RequireJS ready, you can let sbt-rjs does it thing. Here is my setup for reference:

```
/** javascripts/main.js **/
'use strict';

requirejs.config({
    paths:{
        'jquery': ['../lib/jquery/jquery'],
        'react': ['../lib/react/react'],
        'bootstrap': ['../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap'],
        'react-bootstrap': ['../lib/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap']
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'react-bootstrap': {
            deps: ['react']
        }
    }
});
```

Remember to have square brackets, otherwise CDN replacement will not happen.

For the non-requirejs ready scripts, you should not have square brackets when declaring the `paths`. Otherwise, rjs will refuse to build with error `path fallback not supported`. Of course, you won't get the CDN benefit.
Just a side note, RequireJS css optimization works, too. But only limited to inlining the css, like the regular Requirejs does.

Comment: Thanks! I expected that the `requirejs.config` would be generated, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Correction, you don't need the square brackets for cdn replacement to kick in.

Comment: A few things to point out...  `sbt-rjs` does not use the WebJar RequireJS configs.  So you have to manually create your configs when using `sbt-rjs`.  The built-in WebJar RequireJS config used to come from `webjars-requirejs.js` but now comes from the `pom.xml` and is exposed via `webjars-locator` for client-side RequireJS module loading.  The NPM and Bower WebJars should work just like the Classic WebJars for `sbt-rjs` since they get extracted in the same way.